# Is it possible Randomly generate and privately store data using Chainlink?

Tags: solidity, chainlink, oracles

I'm working on a social coordination game for the Chainlink Constellation Hackathon.  Game mechanics are similar to Mafia, Bang! or AmongUs where roles are assigned at the onset of the game.  Roles must be kept secret and persist throughout the game.  Roles also must be query-able in a way that keeps roles secret.  I know data like this cannot be stored and kept secret on chain like:

```
playerOneRole = villain; 
playerTwoRole = superhero;
```

as anyone has access to it given the open nature of a blockchain.

My question is, does Chainlink offer a way to randomly generate this data, keep it a secret, and store it for the course of a game? Mixicles look like a possible answer but I'm not sure if they are available.

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, Chainlink VRF can be used to generate a random number that is used to assign roles to players.

The VRF output is a cryptographic proof that the random number was generated fairly and securely.
The VRF output can be stored on-chain and used to verify the roles of players throughout the game.
Mixicles can be used to shuffle the roles of players so that they are not revealed to anyone until the game starts.

Thanks.